# Global menu is very sluggish in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, globalmenu

Ever since my upgrade to 13.10 the global menu is very sluggish at times.

And by this I mean that after clicking a menu it sometimes takes a while for the actual menu to show.

I know there's an issue where certain applications don't integrate with the global menu anymore, but this seems something else.

Has anyone else noticed it, and maybe know a fix?

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed the same problem. Among others, thats why I removed global menu in Ubuntu. Seems to work. Firefox and the other applications do not have a global menu anymore. "Files" aka "Nautilus" do not have a menu-bar at all (and nothing in global menu) but as I can remember I never needed it (is there any menu anyway?) There is no menu for Chromium anymore. But seriousely: I cannot remember if there was any before I removed the global menu. Anything in chromium seems to be reachable via the menu-button at the right side.

For short: so far everything seems to be fine with disabling global menu.